# Testing a 'stale' element with Selenium and rspec

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, rspec

Still a newbie to RSpec and Ruby, so apologies for any obvious errors, omissions, etc in my question.

What I'm looking to test using RSpec (with Selenium Webdriver) is the following;

1) I've (randomly) selected a make of car from a drop down menu

2) From this selected make, I then (randomly) selected a corresponding model of car from a drop down menu

3) Then pressed "Search" button and a list of, for example, BMW 3-Series cars were correctly displayed.

What I now need to do using RSpec is test that the (randomly selected) make and model names are displayed in a page heading and in the URL.

For example, selecting BMW 3-Series will result in the URL ending in /bmw/3-series and a heading on the page will read "BMW 3-Series Cars For Sale".

However, the problem I'm having is that a 'Stale Element' error message is being displayed when I run the test.

I know why the error is displayed (because the elements used to select the make and model are 'lost' when the Search button is pressed, as a new page opens which does not contain these elements), but I don't know how to get around this problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 # This generates a random manufacturer
    manuselect = @driver.find_element(:id, 'ctl00_contentHolder_topFullWidthContent_ctlCarsForSaleSearch_ctlUsedCarsSearchTab_ddlManufacturer_Control')
    manufacturer = manuselect.find_elements(:tag_name => 'value').sample
    #puts manufacturer.text
    manufacturer.click
    sleep 7
    # This generates a random model
    modelselect = @driver.find_element(:id, 'ctl00_contentHolder_topFullWidthContent_ctlCarsForSaleSearch_ctlUsedCarsSearchTab_ddlRange_Control')
    carmodelrange = modelselect.find_elements(:tag_name => 'value').sample
    puts carmodelrange.text
    carmodelrange.click
    sleep 5
    # Click on the Search button
    @driver.find_element(:id, 'ctl00_contentHolder_topFullWidthContent_ctlCarsForSaleSearch_ctlUsedCarsSearchTab_btnSearch').click
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to store the text you're going to look for into variables before the elements disappear from the page

```
manufacturer_name = manufacturer.text
modelrange_name = carmodelrange.text
#click the search button...
# the following expectations require Capybaras matchers, use whatever expecations are equivalent with whatever you're using
expect(page).to have_current_path(/#{Regexp.quote(manufacturer_name)}\/#{Regexp.quote(modelrange_name)}$/)
expect(page).to have_text("#{manufacturer_name} #{modelrange_name}")
```

Comment: Yey, this answer works exactly how I'd hoped! Many thanks for your help and for your prompt answer, really appreciated. Something that may seem trivial to most can take a long time for someone that's relatively new to RSpec/Selenium/WebDriver, so thanks for not ignoring my question.